# Datagridview not showing data at first time in tabpage

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a datagridview in tabpage2 and I have a search button tabpage1 to fill datagridview. When I search and click tabpage2 datagridview showing empty rows I go back to tabpage1 and click again search and then go to tabpage2 datagridview showing data, why this is happening?

```
Dim daPA As New OracleDataAdapter
Dim dtPA As New DataTable()

Dim cmd As New OracleCommand("select * from POLICY_SUBAGENT_DETAIL where POLICY_REFER =:Vno", sgcnn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Vno", OracleDbType.NVarchar2).Value = TxtPolicyRefer.Text.ToString.Trim

dtPA.Clear()
daPA = New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
daPA.Fill(dtPA)
DgvSubAgent.AutoGenerateColumns = False
DgvSubAgent.DataSource = dtPA

If dtPA.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To dtPA.Rows.Count - 1
        DgvSubAgent.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = dtPA.Rows(i).Item("SUBAGENT_NAME").ToString.Trim
        'DgvSubAgent.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = dtPA.Rows(i).Item("BUSINESS_SHARE").ToString.Trim
        'DgvSubAgent.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = dtPA.Rows(i).Item("COMM_P").ToString.Trim
        DgvSubAgent.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = dtPA.Rows(i).Item("COMM_VALUE").ToString

    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a trick, before fill the datagridview add a line `TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1`

like :

```
TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1  ' where datagridview control placed,     
DgvSubAgent.DataSource = dtPA
```

then before `end sub`, add a line `TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0` --- where search button

Answer (score 0):

The `TabControl` is implemented such that controls on each `TabPage` don't get created until that `TabPage` is selected.  If you select the tab containing the grid before populating that grid then you should find it will work as expected.  You can do that in code, simply by adding a line above what you already have.  If you don't want to select the tab then I would imagine that there's a way to force creation of the controls on that `TabPage`.  I'd have to test to be sure but I would expect that calling `CreateControl` on the `TabPage` would do the trick.